# Access Query to retrieve awards active during a fiscal year

Tags: date, ms-access

Below is a sample of some data I have on award start and close dates. And, from a separate FY table, I have details on the fiscal year-its start and end dates.

Is there a way to create a query that states For Award #1, what fiscal years was this award active? If the start and close dates for the award fall within the fiscal year, then that would be considered active.

Award #1 active during Fiscal years: 2015, 2016, 2017 and 2018

Award #2 active during Fiscal years: 2015 and 2016

Award #3 active during Fiscal years: 2016, 2017 and 2018

```
Award# |Start_date | Close_date
-------+-------------+----------+
1      | 01/05/15  | 01/07/18
2      | 01/06/15  | 01/10/16
3      | 02/05/16  | 2/11/18



FY   |Start_date | End_date
-----+-----------+----------+
2015 | 07/01/14  | 06/30/15
2016 | 07/01/15  | 06/30/16
2017 | 07/01/16  | 06/30/17
2018 | 07/01/17  | 06/30/18
```

Comment: Please learn to tag your questions properly. Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it...
Create a query that will select the 'low' and 'high' FY's from the 'Award' table (I named it Query3):

```
SELECT a.AwardNbr, IIf(Month([a.Start_Date])<7,Year([a.Start_Date]),Year([a.Start_Date])+1) AS FYLow, IIf(Month([a.Close_Date])<7,Year([a.Close_Date]),Year([a.Close_Date])+1) AS FYHi
FROM Award AS a;
```

Then create another query that uses the output of Query3 and joins to the FY table:

```
SELECT Query3.AwardNbr, Query3.FYLow, Query3.FYHi, FY_tbl.FY, FY_tbl.StartDate, FY_tbl.EndDate
FROM Query3, FY_tbl
WHERE (((FY_tbl.FY)>=[FYLOW] And (FY_tbl.FY)<=[FYHi]))
ORDER BY Query3.AwardNbr, FY_tbl.FY;
```

The output will list all FY's involved with an Award date range.